# Innodb mutex locking ?!? Inserts start stacking after 18-24hours, restart required

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

We have a fairly high end box running mysqld 5.5.20.

The cpu configuration is dual quad core xeons.

It has 32 gb ram.

It has a quad intel ssd configuration running raid 0+1.

On a fairly busy service what starts to happen is that after about 18 to 24 hours of being up, once in a while, every few hours, there will be a 1min period where ALL inserts will start stacking. The strange thing is that using mytop even memory table inserts / updates are shown as executing for 'many' seconds.

More ofen then not even without a restart it will return to normal.... only to do it again.

A restart always fixed the issue, for another 18 to 24 hours.

All munins look ok.

Help!

Comment: Some scrubbed copies of innodb status and process list when the problem is occurring would be helpful

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB tables?  Please provide your my.cnf, SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G, and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

Comment: 100% innodb tables. Will add the show engine innodb status to original question.

Comment: In your question, when you said `even memory table inserts / updates are shown as executing for 'many' seconds`, do you mean that you have tables that use the MEMORY storage engine?

Comment: Maybe you are experiencing so-called InnoDB "furious flushing" issue. You could check if that's the case for checking if buffer page write activity spikes at the same time query performance drop.

Comment: Do you have `performance_schema` enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my problem if you have the `performance_schema` enabled, solved after the upgrade of MySql server version.

Starting from 5.5.16 to 5.5.22 is affected by a deadlock. 
No queries can be run when it happens:
Bug 13898343 - THREAD LOOPS ENDLESSLY IN LF_PINBOX_PUT_PINS WHILE HOLDING LOCK_THREAD_COUNT

```
An infinite thread loop could develop within Performance Schema, 
causing the server to become unresponsive. (Bug #13898343)
```

[See changelog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-23.html)

First of all try disabling `performance_schema`

Hope his helps